# full calendar background color selected disappear on prev/next button click

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have added some CSS classes in the day click event for giving some background color to the selected dates 
However, when a user clicks the prev, next, or today buttons, added classes are removed and previous color selected are lost.How can I retain the selected color even on button click

```
$('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
  locale: userlang,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
  },

  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    debugger;

    alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
    component.set('v.selecteddate1', date.toISOString());

    console.log('selected val--->'+component.get("v.selecteddate"));
    //alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

    alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

    // change the day's background color just for fun
    $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
  },

  editable: true,
  events: data,

  eventClick: function(event,jsEvent, view) {
    debugger;
    //alert(event.url);
    console.log('event url:'+event.url);
    console.log('event starttime:'+event.StartDateTime);
    //component.find("expdate1").set("v.selecteddate",event.StartDateTime);
    alert('test'+view.name);
    component.set()
  },

  eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title+' '+'Hora de inicio:'+new Date(event.start).toDateString()+' Hora de finalización: '+new Date(event.end).toDateString());
  }
  //alert('Hello'+paramvalueget);
});
```

Comment: you'd have to keep a separate list of days that have been highlighted. Then handle the viewRender callback and re-apply the relevant ones again when the view and/or the date range changes. This is because changing the view and/or date destroys all the HTML markup that was in the calendar previously and creates it again for the new view, so any customisations are also lost

Comment: @ADyson in my case on next button click only function next in full calendar js is getting called. Can you please post some code snippet

Comment: How can I get the selected date's HTML in jquery code

Comment: outside of fullCalendar, define an empty array to hold selected dates. when dayClick runs, as well as changing the background colour, add the date to your array. Then when viewRender runs, loop through the array of dates. If any come within the new date range of the view, you can set the background colour of that date element again (they all have CSS classes by which you can find them, and a date attribute to narrow it down to a date - examine the fullCalendar HTML using your developer tools and you'll see what you need to use to find the right HTML element for highlighting)