# BackGround colour of the day disappears on 'prev' & 'next' click

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar in my project. I gave background color to date on `dayClick` function. But If we move to the next month by using `next` icon and then back to the  month on which days are selected,background color of that selected dates disappear. Is there any way to persist that color?

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'aquamarine');
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to see some more code in a fiddle.

Comment: See the comments by ADyson on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210292/full-calendar-background-color-selected-disappear-on-prev-next-button-click) for an idea how to do that.